# Did I break my project by running `npm audit fix --force`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, recharts

I was building a React project with Vite and it was going great. I needed to add some charts and found out about the recharts package and really liked it so downloaded it into my project with the command `npm i recharts`.

I get the following message:

[high severity vulnerabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An8KL.jpg)

I then ran `npm audit`, `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force` and got this:

[lots of warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k9AO.jpg)

Now when I try to start up my project with `npm run dev` I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: import_events.default is not a constructor
```

It says it's coming from a file called Events.js but I do not have such a file in my project.

I tried running `npm audit fix --force` multiple times like my terminal told me to but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly happened to your project but it seems that's because security issues you can read more in [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities)  ,I think reinstalling modules and clearing cache might do what you want :

for clearing cache : `npm cache clean –force`
and for reinstalling modules : `npm ci --force`